# Using FreeImage convert hdr to jpg

Tags: python, python-imageio

How can I use ImageIO's FreeImage to convert and hdr to a jpeg image?

I've written a function that takes and EXR and converts it to a jpg and the results looks like this:

[image]

So I'm stumped on how to take an HDR and convert it to a jpg with similar results. I downloaded the HDR from here for free: https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/download.php?h=cayley_interior&r=1k

I'm just not sure how to go about converting the floating number range in the hdr to a jpg image bit-depth.

HDR > JPG

```
import imageio
import os

def convert_hdr_to_jpg(filepath):
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        return False

    directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(filepath)
    if not extension.lower() in ['.hdr', '.hdri']:
        return False

    # imageio.plugins.freeimage.download() #DOWNLOAD IT
    image = imageio.imread(filepath, format='HDR-FI')
    output = os.path.join(directory, filename + '.jpg')
    imageio.imwrite(output, image)
```

EXR > JPG

```
import os, json, logging, time, random
from math import sqrt
from collections import namedtuple
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import OpenEXR
import Imath

def convert_exr_to_jpg(filepath):
    '''
    Description:
        Generates a jpg image for the supplied exr file

    Args:
        filepath (str): filepath to image

    Returns:
        bool: Returns True on success otherwise returns False
    '''
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        log.error('Missing file: {}'.format(filepath))
        return False

    name, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))

    if extension not in ['.exr']:
        log.warning('Invalid image file format: {}'.format(filepath))
        return False

    File = OpenEXR.InputFile(filepath)
    PixType = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
    DW = File.header()['dataWindow']
    Size = (DW.max.x - DW.min.x + 1, DW.max.y - DW.min.y + 1)

    rgb = [numpy.fromstring(File.channel(c, PixType), dtype=numpy.float32) for c in 'RGB']
    for i in range(3):
        rgb[i] = numpy.where(rgb[i]<=0.0031308,
                (rgb[i]*12.92)*255.0,
                (1.055*(rgb[i]**(1.0/2.4))-0.055) * 255.0)

    rgb8 = [Image.frombytes("F", Size, c.tostring()).convert("L") for c in rgb]
    # rgb8 = [Image.fromarray(c.astype(int)) for c in rgb]
    output = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filepath), name + '.jpg'))
    Image.merge("RGB", rgb8).save(output, quality=80)
    log.info('Created: {}'.format(output))
```

Comment: Do you have to solve it with openimage io or can you use `opencv` as well?

Comment: Either one is fine to use

Comment: openCV doesn't support hdr though.

Comment: web link you have mentioned is broken. Can you attach a reference in your question.

Comment: Also can you add result image you are getting from existing code and results you are expecting.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install -y openimageio-tools
oiiotool probe.hdr -o probe.png
# https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/discussions/3579
# https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openimageio
```